# Exclamation mark in C array (identity matrix)

Tags: c, matrix, identity

I know there is a thread about explanation of `!` in C, but I did not understand it fully so here we go. From my understanding `number!` will return 0 for a non-zero number and 1 for 0. I saw a few code online and to identify if the matrix is an identity matrix people used something along the lines of:

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] != 1 && a[j][i] != 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (flag == 1 )
    printf("It is identity matrix \n");
else
    printf("It is not a identity matrix \n");
```

With user inputted matrix size and values with a being the matrix. My question is how does `!` mark help in anyway to identify whether it is an identity matrix or not if all it can do is return an input of 1 and 0s. And would there be any other way to identify an identity matrix without the use of?

Comment: The `!` here is part of the `!=` operator, which means "not equal to". You seem to be mistaking it for the "logical negation" operator here.

Comment: `a != b` is equvalent to `!(a == b)`.

Answer (score 2):

`!` **always** returns an int (thanks to [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) for pointing that out), it stands for **Logical NOT** in this case and just **complements** a boolean expression, if a boolean expression evaluates to `true`, say `boolean ex = true` then `!ex` would resolve to `false` (and finally 0) which is the **complement** of `true`.

In case of comparison, `==` is used to check for equality and `!=` is used to check **inequality** and both of these result in a `boolean` value which finally gets evaluated to `int`.

Comment: "*! does not return an int,*": Not quite right. From the [C11 Standard (draft) 6.5.3.3/5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5): "*The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares
unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. **The result has type `int`**.*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @alk You're right, I was talking in context of ! being used on booleans, made an edit.

Comment: Sry, but to confirm with to above cited Standard applying the `!` -operator ***always*** needs evaluate to an `int`. You could use it on any scalar type. Look at a C `_Bool` like a 1-bit unsigned integer with a rank lower than any other integer type.

Comment: Even `!(42 == 42)` would evaluate to an `int` (of value 0). As well as `!42.` would do.

Comment: But an `if` statement needs an expression that evaluates to boolean right?

Comment: Following the C11 Standard 6.8.4.1/1: "*The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar type*" The *controlling expression* needs to be ***unequal to 0*** for the *first substatement* to be executed. (6.8.4.1/2).

Comment: The background to the Standard being worded like this most likely is that prior to C99 there simply was no type to represent booleans.

Comment: @alk Thank you very much for helping, I made a final edit you can verify to see if I finally got it right?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not check if the matrix is an identity matrix or not. You do not need `!` to find out, either: all you need to do is to check that all matrix elements are zero, except on the main diagonal, when `i==j`, in which case the element must be `1`.

Comparison `i == j` returns zero or one, so all you need to do is checking that for all values `i` and `j` the element `a[i][j]` is equal to the result of comparison `i==j`:

```
int flag = 1;
for (i = 0 ; flag && i < row ; i++) {
    for (j = 0; flag && j < column; j++) {
        int mainDiagonal = (i==j);
        flag = a[i][j] == mainDiagonal;
    }
}
if (flag == 1 )
    printf("It is identity matrix \n");
else
    printf("It is not a identity matrix \n");
```

Note several changes to the loops: since `break` lets you break out of only one loop, I changed continuation conditions to check the `flag`.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation point in C (and many other languages) stands for the logical NOT sign.  i.e.-  '!='  is 'NOT EQUAL'.
In C specifically NOT on a non-zero number will return 0, while NOT on 0 will return 1 because numbers can be used as TRUE or FALSE notations as well (0 = FALSE, non-zero = TRUE).

Hope that helps

Comment: 0 is a number, so "NOT on a number" is not a very successful way of putting it. You might have meant "non-zero number".

Comment: @unwind Quite true- fixed  :)

Answer (score 1):

`!=` Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not. If the values are not equal, then the condition becomes true.   `(A != B`) is true if  A holds 10 and B holds 20.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already addressed that `!=` means **not equal** but there are other things not covered.

First of all: **Your code does not check for identity matrix**

Just give it a try with this matrix:

```
int a[2][2] = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
```

Further, I don't think any answer has addressed this part:

> And would there be any other way to identify an identity matrix without the use of?

Yes, you can write it without use of `!=`. And it can be done in many ways. Here is just one example:

```
flag = 1;
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == 1) continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (a[i][j] == 0) continue;
        }

        flag = 0;
    }
}
if (flag == 1 )
    printf("It is identity matrix \n");
else
    printf("It is not a identity matrix \n");
```

Not very nice code but it is a way to do it without `!=`

For a real cool way of checking for identity matrix (without using `!=`) see the answer from @dasblinkenlight : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42328490/4386427

Answer (score 0):

! and != are two different operators.

! is called NOT Operator. This operator reverses the result of the expression it operates on. For example, if the expression evaluates to a non-zero value, then applying ! Operator to it results into a 0. Vice versa, if the expression evaluates to zero then on applying ! Operator to it makes it 1, a nonzero value. The final result after applying ! operator will 0 or 1 is considered to be false or true respectively.

Whereas != is a relational operator, which is used to check if the two operands, on which the != is applied, are not equal. != is called not equals to operator and used to compare two quantities.

Now on your question

```
if (a[i][j] != 1 && a[j][i] != 0)
    {
        flag = 0;
        break;
    }
```

In above fragment of code the condition will true if and only if a[i][j] is not equals to 1 and a[j][i] is not equals to 0. If so, code inside if will execute.
Here in the code, if the condition is true it will evaluate to 1 which is true, otherwise 0 which is false. As you said "how does ! mark help in anyway to identify whether it is an identity matrix or not", it is not ! mark it is != mark help to identify if the matrix is identity.

Hope this will help.